# Back to Summary Button in SSRS reports

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports

i have developed SSRS report with has summary report which is linked to six sub reports. i have provided  eight parameters in summary report to make it user friendly. But when linked to sub reports it is working fine, but i want to provide back to summary button(link) in other sub reports.And it should be in a such  a way that summary report should not be reset.(i.e Parameter selected should not change in summary report). 
Any one has a solution for it.
Waiting for your positive response.
Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding buttons to the ReportViewer is a mind field at best. (Although, using the .NET web version, it's possible to add something like a ["Clear/Reset Button"](http://insomniacgeek.com/how-to-add-a-clear-button-to-sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs/) using JavaScript.)

However, the functionality you are after is already available, see the Microsoft Documentation on [Configuring and Using the ReportViewer Toolbar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251670.aspx).

Comment: Thank you kidCode , i can try this.